# Find value of a matrix at a specific position

Tags: math, matrix, numbers, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic

Assume I have a matrix of 5 rows and 10 columns. It is filled with natural numbers row-wise ([0,0] = 1, [0,1] = 2,.....[9,4] = 50). Is there any way of finding out what element is present in a specific position, given the matrix indices? Considering I have a program that takes [9,3] as an input, the program should print the value 49.

I can do this using a loop and a 2D array. But I want to know if there is any mathematical solution to this, like a formula or an equation, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By your description, the formula is

```
A[i,j] = 5*i+j+1
```

Generally, if there are `m` positions `[0..m-1]` in first and `n` positions `[0..n-1]` in second place, then a similar formula is

```
A[i,j] = n*i+j+1
```

This reflects an increase by 1 along the rows and a jump by `n` when going down one row.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I realized I made an error while typing out my question. Since it's a 5 rows and 10 columns matrix, [4, 9] will be 50. Hence the formula will be 10*i+j+1   :D